# Codeigniter redirect main folders (application, system)

Tags: php, codeigniter, nginx

I build an application with codeigniter and I wondered if it was possible to redirect access to major folders such as application, system.

Currently, I get the message "Directory access is forbidden." but can we not go redirect to one same controller ? it is not possible to have a controller named "application"?

I use Nginx 1.4.4. Thank you.

Comment: Maybe its a better idea to use routing for the "application" thingie.
Anyways: http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/reserved_names.html

Comment: I would go with @IvankaTodorova solution

Comment: I agree too, but is there a way to not display that message to my users ?

Comment: Personally, I don't think it's possible. Unless you want to play with Apache core code.

Comment: Create an index.php file in system and application folder and in that have a code to redirect.

Comment: Yes I will do this way, but unfortunatelly we can't use relative path in redirect code..

Comment: Aah it seems that : header('Location: ../myfolder/mycontroller'); works. I'll test and post it as my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Ok you can do it by creating an index.php file in your folder an putting a redirection :

```
<?php
/**
 * Redirect to application index controller
 */
header('Location: ../application/index');
```

It worked for me.